# After rebooting, the landscape service is unavailable

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have installed openstack landscape. After that I needed to to reboot my hypervisor, but after the reboot landscape is not available.

What should I do to be able to reboot without reinstalling landscape autopilot?

Comment: I'll need a paste of /var/log/juju/unit-landscape-0.log to help more (or at least a paste of any interesting errors you see in there).  It could be a number of things, but a reboot of just landscape should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following to attempt to restart the services:

```
juju run --service landscape,landscape-msg 'sudo lsctl restart'
```

For help on the root cause, I'll need to see more information, namely `/var/log/juju/unit-landscape-0.log` from landscape/0:

```
# to get there:
juju ssh landscape/0
```